# Symfony - Asterisk on required label, bug on ChoiceType field

Tags: css, symfony

in my project Symfony 4 I want to put asterisk next to the labels whose fields are mandatory.

According to the doc ', there are several ways to do this: https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/form/form_customization.html#adding-a-required-asterisk-to-field-labels

But the CSS method is the easier.

So in my CSS file, I added this code :

```
label.required:after {
  content: " *";
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

It works to a detail. In forms, when I have a ChoiceType field, the asterisk does not go on the main label but on all possible choices.

[image]

With this HTML render :

```
<div class="col-2">
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <legend class="col-form-label required">Ajouter/Supprimer</legend>
        <div id="role_choix">
            <div class="form-check">
                <input type="radio" id="role_choix_0" name="role[choix]" required="required" class="form-check-input" value="ajouter">
                <label class="form-check-label required" for="role_choix_0">Ajouter</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input type="radio" id="role_choix_1" name="role[choix]" required="required" class="form-check-input" value="supprimer">
                <label class="form-check-label required" for="role_choix_1">Supprimer</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

This is my formType :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('choix', ChoiceType::class, [
                'label' => 'Ajouter/Supprimer',
                'choices' => [
                    'Ajouter' => 'ajouter',
                    'Supprimer' => 'supprimer',
                ],
                'multiple' => false,
                'expanded' => true,
            ])
            ->add('role', ChoiceType::class, [
                'label' => "Ajouter un rôle à cet utilisateur",
                'choices' => [
                    'Admin' => 'admin',
                    'Direction' => 'direction',
                    'RH' => 'rh',
                ]
            ])
        ;
    }
```

And my Twig :

```
{{form_start(form)}}
    <div class="row items-align-center">
        <div class="col-md-2">{{form_row(form.choix)}}</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">{{form_row(form.role)}}</div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enregistrer</button>
    {{form_end(form)}}
```

So the bug is only on radio buttons

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Can you please also add your Template code (twig)? Are you using one of the existing form themes, e.g. `bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig`? If so, which one?

Comment: Yes I updated my code, et yes I use the ```bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a very old question, but I found that this solution works for me:

```css
label.required:not(.form-check-label):after {
    content: "\2000*";
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the css property on label and that's working. What you want for radios is to put it on legend. You have to adapt the css selector.
Does the radio group and the select label share one class attribute  ?